# Distribute options uniquely algorithm

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have a 2 dimensional array. Each subarray consists out of a number of options. I am trying to write a script which picks one of these options for each row. The chosen options have to be unique. An example:

```
$array = array(
    1 => array(3,1),
    2 => array(3),
    3 => array(1,5,3),
);
```

With a solution:

```
$array = array(
    1 => 1,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 5,
);
```

I have finished the script, but i am not sure if it is correct. This is my script. The description of what i am doing is in the comments.

```
function pickUnique($array){
    //Count how many times each option appears
    $counts = array();
    foreach($array AS $options){
        if(is_array($options)){
            foreach($options AS $value){
                //Add count
                $counts[$value] = (isset($counts[$value]) ? $counts[$value]+1 : 1);
            }
        }
    }
    asort($counts);

    $didChange = false;


    foreach($counts AS $value => $count){

        //Check one possible value, starting with the ones that appear the least amount of times
        $key = null;
        $scoreMin = null;

        //Search each row with the value in it. Pick the row which has the lowest amount of other options
        foreach($array AS $array_key => $array_options){
            if(is_array($array_options)){
                if(in_array($value,$array_options)){
                    //Get score
                    $score = 0;


                    $score = count($array_options)-1;

                    if($scoreMin === null OR ($score < $scoreMin)){
                        //Store row with lowest amount of other options
                        $scoreMin = $score;
                        $key        = $array_key;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if($key !== null){
            //Store that we changed something while running this function
            $didChange = true;


            //Change to count array. This holds how many times each value appears.
            foreach($array[$key] AS $delValue){
                $counts[$delValue]--;
            }

            //Remove chosen value from other arrays
            foreach($array AS $rowKey => $options){
                if(is_array($options)){
                    if(in_array($value,$options)){
                        unset($array[$rowKey][array_search($value,$options)]);
                    }
                }
            }

            //Set value
            $array[$key] = $value;
        }

    }

    //validate, check if every row is an integer
    $success = true;
    foreach($array AS $row){
        if(is_array($row)){
            $success = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$success AND $didChange){
        //Not done, but we made changes this run so lets try again
        $array = pickUnique($array);
    }elseif(!$success){
        //Not done and nothing happened this function run, give up.
        return null;
    }else{
        //Done
        return $array;
    }


}
```

My main problem is is that i have no way to verify if this is correct. Next to that i also am quite sure this problem has been solved a lot of times, but i cannot seem to find it. The only way i can verificate this (as far as i know) is by running the code a lot of times for random arrays and stopping when it encounters an insolvable array. Then i check that manually. So far the results are good, but this way of verication is ofcourse not correct.

I hope somebody can help me, either with the solution, the name of the problem or the verification method.

Comment: @MikeBrant OP says: _this way of verication is ofcourse not correct._ we only review working code at CodeReview

Comment: @MikeBrant The problem is basically how to go from the example array to the solution, and i am quite certain this is a common problem which has been solved already.

Comment: This looks to me like an [exact cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover).

Comment: @Caridorc I think he means that his code is working, and it's working correctly for a limited number of test input cases, but that that in itself doesn't prove that it is correct for all input cases. Surely that would be ok on Code Review? Or is CR only for optimisation, not logic errors?